# Paperclip S3 error, No route matches [GET] "/assets/:s3_domain_url"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm trying to use Paperclip with S3 in my Rails app. But whenever I try to upload a file, I get a 404 error saying `No route matches [GET] "/assets/:s3_domain_url"`.

This is how I have set up Paperclip defaults in config/environments/development.rb:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => {
       :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
       :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
       :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
   }
}
```

these are the Paperclip settings in the model

```
has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/assets/profile/iama.png"
validates_attachment :photo, :size => { :in => 0..1000.kilobytes }
validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => /image/
```

Can you help me please?
Thanks

Comment: Did you create the environment variables S3_BUCKET_NAME, AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY?

Answer (score 0):

problem solved, i set up my environment variables incorrectly, putting quotes around S3_BUCKET_NAME, AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID etc